# tablet and mobile same layout with bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I design same type of layout for mobile and tablets with bootstrap 3.

My navbar doesn't look the same in mobile and tablet. The navbar in tablet looks same as desktop. But I want it to look like mobile.

Comment: Try to illustrate or provide more information about your question. Apparently you need to manage your style using the styles `col-` See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I'm trying to use offcanvas http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/. But it works fine in mobile. But for tablets it looks same as desktop. I wanted it to look like mobile

Comment: So you want the minimised navbar for your tablet?

Comment: Yes. I want to have the 3 horizontal lines kind of navbar for tablet as well.

Comment: Make changes in the media query.. for you to have the same navbar in tablet also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap 3's solution is here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

```
Customize the collapsing point

Depending on the content in your navbar, you might need to change the point at 
which your navbar switches between collapsed and horizontal mode. Customize the 
@grid-float-breakpoint variable or add your own media query.
```

So you solution is to either `Customize the @grid-float-breakpoint variable or add your own media query.`

so make a **MQ css** like :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)/*or ur preferred width*/ {
 /* style here */
}
```

i'll suggest you to make a separate css for this and let bootstrap file as it is!

Answer (score 0):

/* Tablet Devices, Desktop and Laptop Screens */

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 // Code to minimize menu

.navbar-collapse {
max-height: 340px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
overflow-x: visible;
border-top: 1px solid transparent;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.collapse {
display: none;
}

}
```